# How to disconnect an external browser launched inside w3m from w3m?

Tags: browser, w3m

Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> in w3m will launch external browser to show the current page from w3m. However, once the external browser is launched, w3m is frozen, waiting the user to quit the external browser before going back to the normal mode. Is it possible to config it such that it can launch the external browser to the background? So that I can use it and the external browser at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the [FAQ](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/FAQ#www).

Hit <kbd>o</kbd> to go into options and specify

```
browsername %s &
```

where `browsername` is the command to invoke said browser.